# Interpretation of hex documentation for screen control

Tags: serial-port, controls, communication, lg

I am working on a project where I have to send a command via rs232 cable to an NEC screen in order to make it turn off as well as change its input. I have already done this same process with an LG TV, but the documentation on this NEC is much more complicated. [This document](http://www.necdisplay.com/documents/UserManuals/External_Control_P.V.X-series.pdf) shows the commands that I need, particularly the power command on page 36.

Unlike the LG TV, which uses 8 bit commands, this command is around 20 bits long, and I am having a lot of trouble deciphering the correct code. Is there anyone who has more experience interpreting these kinds of documents and is willing to give me a hand?

Also, the command that I have tried so far for power command is:

```
01 30 0A 30 41 30 43 02 43 32 30 33 44 36 30 30 30 34 03 77 0D
```

Comment: First of all, is the connection okay? Do you have an answer back ( everytime) ?

Comment: I have used the cable that sends the commands to the TV multiple times. It works fine. Also, I believe that I may have solved part of the problem. The part of the command that says 77 is not arbitrarily assigned as I originally thought. It is the XOR of the 16 commands that come before it. The manual says D1 xor D2 xor D3... xor D16. Now I just have to figure out how to understand that notation, because I don't think XOR is commutative. @noidea

Comment: But is the connection ok? Have you tried a serial port monitor? idk if the commutative part is a problem cause if the string length is fixed, u just have to format it properly

Comment: @noidea I use realterm to send the files, and no errors were thrown when I try to send the file.

Comment: Well, that leaves us with the string composition. Have u tried [Hercules](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html) ?

Comment: @noidea I have not, unfortunately, the site says that the program is intended for windows 7, and this project is intended to run of windows 10.

Comment: So, do you have a message back the way you're doing it ?

Comment: @noidea No, when the commands don't go through, there is no response from the realterm terminal.

Comment: That's where Hercules could help. Cause my idea is that your not composing the string properly

Comment: @noidea I finally got a response from the TV. The input does not change, but I get back this string in the terminal: SOH - 0 - 0 - A - A - 0 - 4 -STX - B - E - ETX - STX - CR.

Comment: what did you do? the string u've sent i mean

Comment: @noidea I tried to change the input from VGA to S Video, Display Port, or DVI. All of those gave the same response: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dxydw3mld6v431t/2016-04-15.jpg?dl=0 (The one command that gave a different response is the one that turned off the TV)

Comment: but u actually turned off the tv with a command?